# Am I obligated to use Stateful Widgets to dispose stream controllers in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

When dealing with **streams** and **stream controllers** in Flutter, am I forced to use Stateful Widgets to dispose the controller? or is there any other way to do so using Stateless Widgets?

This is how it's done normally in Stateful Widgets:

```
void dispose() {
 _myController.dispose();
 super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: That's at least good practice. It can cause errors (usually related to "mounted") if a stream emits events after a widget was removed from the view but not yet garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use provider package for flutter. It has callback for dispose where you can dispose of your blocs. Providers are inherited widgets and provides a clean way to manage the blocs with streams. With this approach you can go completely stateless.

Comment: I don't think this accurately answers the question, the OP is asking strictly about stream controllers and streams, which could also be handled with the provider package but no enough detail was provided.